# admob ads are not working in signed apk,it worked perfect at debug version

Tags: android, google-play, admob, adsense, signed-apk

admob ads are not working in signed apk,it worked perfect at debug version.

in my first version of apk i shared my debug version in android with ads,now my app have more than **200** users,so i decided to publish it on play store but after i signed apk , admob  is not working......

Why does the signed apk not showing ads?

Is it possible to publish apps in debug mode?

i tried to close verify the **passwords** but it has no use

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ProGuard when signing your apk/bundle? If that is the case the following rules worked for me:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info {*;}
```

If you are not using ProGuard make sure you are not using the test ad unit IDs. Other than that you should check whether you have setup your Ad Unit IDs properly from the AdMob dashboard and see whether requests are coming in. Additionally, you can check whether the callbacks inside your app are returning an error code 3 with message No fill. If that is the case - this is totally expected behaviour, since you cannot expect to have a 100% fill rate all the time.

Also, Add release build configuration in build-gradle (app level) file.

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('keystore_file_path_stored_in_your_computer')
        storePassword 'add_your_keystore_password'
        keyAlias = 'your_key_alias'
        keyPassword 'your_password'
        if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
            storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        renderscriptDebuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        zipAlignEnabled = false
        multiDexEnabled = false
        if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other ways to fix it works, then do the following. Check your keystore.jks file to make sure it is configured properly to your current project in your build.gradle(app) file, as well as when you build the signed apk or bundle. My keystore.jks files did not match but when I changed it, it worked exactly how it is supposed to function.
It worked for emulators and debug apk before I changed/ fix the issue. None of the other ways described worked for me.